# Recurrent Convolutional Autoencoder in Tensorflow

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, data-science

I am trying to build a recurrent convolutional autoencoder in Tensorflow, but I am having trouble linking the convolutional autoencoder with the recurrent layer.

From my understanding the a Tensorflow RNNCell takes in an input of shape (batch_size, time_steps, info_vector), but my 1D convolutional layer has an output shape of (batch_size, info_vector).  Is there a way to have tensorflow store the previous information vectors. Alternatively do I need to use a 2D convolution, add an extra time_step dimension to the input and then not convolve over that dimension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to expand the dimensionality of the tensor:

```
cnn_out = last_output_of_cnn # for example shape [32,10]
cnn_out = tf.expand_dims(cnn_output, axis=-1) # new shape [32,10,1]
```

You can use this in the first layer of your RNN, where here "timestep" is 10.

Comment: Thanks so much.  I will give this a try.